# Center the button vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need to make sure that the 'Next' button below the video is centered vertically and horizontally within the block with the yellow background.

In addition, the 'click' effect on the button does not seem to work as intended. There is something causing a conflict here and I cannot figure out what.

When I only run the "next-video-button" and "next-video-button:active" CSS rules, everything works perfectly.

You may find my CSS and HTML below.

```css
.course-video {
    background: #f9c70f;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}

.next-video-button {
  transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
 padding: 7px 200px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #888888;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #5a5a5a;
 text-shadow: 1px -2px #888888;
  text-align: center;
}

.next-video-button:active {
 transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.video-title {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 854px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.video-descr {
  width: 854px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-video video-title">Hello</div>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/154094373" width="854" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div class="course-video video-descr"><a href="#" class="next-video-button">NEXT</a></div>
```

Comment: Add text-align:center to .course-video, and play with line-height on .next-video-button to get desired position: https://jsfiddle.net/smhob5pk/1/ P.S. What's wrong with 'click event'?

Comment: @nevermind Thank you very much! However, it centers the content of the first block (with the word 'Hello') as well, which is not really what I want. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, yes, then add text-align to .video-descr: https://jsfiddle.net/smhob5pk/2/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To center the button give it a width and add `margin: 0 auto` and `display: block;` to `.next-video-button`.

The button won't work though because of `a href="#"`. Replace the # with the video URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @James ! This, however, does not center the button vertically.